# Why I can't print out environment variables in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, environment-variables

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  int i = 0;
  while(environ[i]) {
    printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here's my ops:

```
(gdb) n
8       printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
(gdb) p environ[i]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) n
LOGNAME=root
7     while(environ[i]) {
```

As you can see,`printf` can print out `environ[i]`,but `p environ[i]` gives me `Cannot access memory at address 0x0`,why?

Comment: Strange.  I reproduce.  If I add a `ptr = environ` before the while loop, I'm able to use `ptr` but `environ` stay a null pointer.

Comment: Apparently `gdb` starts the process for the program being debugged with no environment.

Comment: @pmg, It has an environment.  I'm using set env in gdb often enough to be sure of that.

Answer (score 10):

gdb resolves the wrong `environ` symbol. <s>I don't know why though.</s> See below as to why.

But you can test it. Change the program to:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  printf("%p\n", &environ);
  while(environ[i]) {
    printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now let's run this in the debugger.

```
(gdb) n
7         printf("%p\n", &environ);
(gdb) n
0x8049760
8         while(environ[i]) {
(gdb) p &environ
$1 = (char ***) 0x46328da0
(gdb)
```

So. The actual program has, during its linking, resolved `environ` to the address 0x8049760.
When gdb wants to access the `environ` symbol, it resolves to 0x46328da0, which is different.

Edit.
It seems your `environ` symbol is actually linked to the `environ@@GLIBC_2.0` symbol.
In gdb write this:

```
(gdb) p environ
```

And hit the tab key (twice), it'll autocomplete the symbols. Which yields:

```
(gdb) p environ
environ             environ@@GLIBC_2.0
```

`environ@@GLIBC_2.0` is the one actually linked to the `extern char **environ`

Printing this yields the same address as the program sees, 0x8049760:

```
(gdb) p &'environ@@GLIBC_2.0'
$9 = ( *) 0x8049760
(gdb) p ((char**)'environ@@GLIBC_2.0')[i]
$10 = 0xbffff6ad "XDG_SESSION_ID=1"
```

So, at one point glibc deprecated the `environ` symbol, and added a newer version

Comment: does that explains why `environ` is different in `printf` and `p`?

Comment: @nos I got a reversed situation where gdb print environ perfectly, but the program inside a shared library cannot (got 0x00 pointer), any ideas how that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are accessed in C/C++ using the function `getenv()` defined in `stdlib.h`. However, using the `envp` parameter of the main function you can use the following example to iterate over environment variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  char **next = envp;

  while (*next) 
  {
    printf("%s\n", *next);
    next++;
  }
  return 0;


}
```

*Tested on a Mac*

Comment: GDB can call functions, though. For example: `call (char*) getenv("PATH")` (It seems to assume the return is an integer without that typecast.) Of course, that function does have to be available, but if the program cares about environment variables, surely it must be!

Comment: Thats not the issue, the _environ / environ variable is not directly supported on all platforms.

Comment: My point was that there's often a way to see environment variables without caring at all whether `environ` or `_environ` is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like grundprinzip said, use getenv(sz) *and remember to null-check the return value*

Alternatively,

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char*[] environ) { 
  int i = 0;
  while(environ[i]) {
    printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the process under debugging is started with

```
execve(binary, NULL, NULL);
```

and the `extern char **environ` gets that 2nd `NULL` even though there's an environment available.

With a little change, your program works both standalone and under `gdb`.

```
/* #include <unistd.h> */           /* no more environ */
#include <stdio.h>

/* extern char **environ; */        /* no more environ */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  int i = 0;
  char **ptr = argv + argc + 1;     /* points to environment, in Un*x */
  while(ptr[i]) {
    printf("%s\n", ptr[i++]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why, and how, that `NULL` gets converted to the proper value inside `gdb` I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  I tried it on my machine and it printed the environment as expected.  You should not need to use getenv().

Are you running this application from the terminal?  If not, you should be.  Other means of executing an application might be calling your binary without passing it the environment.

From the terminal what is your output when you run "env"?  It should output the same list as your program.  It does on my machine.