# How to get environment of a program while debugging it in GDB

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, environment-variables

I am debugging a program in GDB on linux. I am using `getenv` and `setenv` calls to read and set environment variables. For example I am calling `setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);` to set the TZ environment variable for timezone.

To check if the env variable is set I am using GDB command `show environment`. This prints all the environment variables and their values. But it dose not show `TZ` being set.

Even command `show environment TZ` says `Environment variable "TZ" not defined.`

Is their another way to check the environment of the debugged program?

`p *(char *) getenv("TZ")` reuturns correct value `UTC`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `p (char*)getenv("TZ")`?

Comment: Looks like `environ` is NULL. `environ@@GLIBC_2.0` is the one that points to the real environment in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203455/why-i-cant-print-out-environment-variables-in-gdb

Comment: `environ` works fine for me, but it's probably related to the glibc version (among other things).

Comment: @punekr12: OK, I added a way of printing the entire environment to my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The gdb command `show environment` shows an environment which belongs to `gdb` [see note], not the environment of the program being debugged.

Calling `getenv` seems like a totally reasonable approach to printing the running program's environment.

#### Note

Gdb maintains an environment array, initially copied from its own environment, which it uses to start each new child process. `show environment` and `set environment` work on this environment, so `set environment` will change an environment variable for the *next time* you start the program being debugged. Once the program is started, the loader will have copied the environment into the program's address space, and any changes made with `setenv` apply to that array, not the one maintained by `gdb`.

#### Addendum: How to print the debugged program's entire environment

On Linux, every process's environment is available through the pseudofile `/proc/PID/environ`, where `PID` is replaced by the pid of the process. The value of that file is a list of null-terminated strings, so printing it out takes a small amount of work.

Inside gdb, once you've started running the program to be debugged, you can get its pid with `info proc` and then use that to print the entire environment:

```
(gdb) info proc
process 6074
...
(gdb) shell xargs -0 printf %s\\n < /proc/6074/environ
XDG_VTNR=7
KDE_MULTIHEAD=false
...
```

Of course, I could have done that just as easily outside of gdb, from a different terminal.

Comment: I need to see all the env variables of the program for debugging, how to do that ?

Comment: @punekr12: Use the global variable `environ` which is a `char**`; each element points to a string in the form `var=value`

Comment: @punekr12: But unless your program iterates over the variable `environ`, that's pretty well pointless. Just use `getenv` on the variables you are interested in. That will match perfectly with what the program sees.

Comment: `show environment` is not GDB's own environment, it's the environment it will give to processes that it starts, see https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html -- although it starts as a copy of GDB's own environment, it can be modified using `set environment` and `unset environment`, and GDB's own environment is not changed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That's a good point. But it does belong to gdb. I'll try to rejig the answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I had to grab the environment from the proc fs to prove to myself that gdb doesn't just set variables in its own environment :) You're right, it doesn't.

Comment: `proc/PID/environ` does *not* provide the **current** environment variables. As per [`man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) : "*This file contains the **initial environment that was set when the currently executing program was started** [...]. If [...] the process modifies its environment [...], **this file will not reflect those changes**.*

Comment: As @Abdull states, this answer (`shell xargs -0 printf %s\\n < /proc/6074/environ`) does not show any newly-added environment variables added via `setenv()`, nor does it show the updated values of any updated environment variables updated via `setenv()`. I discuss that [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887) and show how to call `getenv()` directly in GDB to read new or updated values after program start. So, anyone using this answer needs to at least understand that limitation.

Answer (score 4):

You can alter GDB's view of the environment with `set environment TZ =UTC` but that doesn't affect a running program, only the environment that will be used next time an inferior process is started.

You can inspect a running inferior process' current environment via the global variable `environ`

Comment: Upvoted becuse you talk about inspecting a program's environment variables via [environ](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html). Now, here's [my answer on exactly how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903706/4561887).

Answer (score 3):

The [accepter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32917097/4561887) (`shell xargs -0 printf %s\\n < /proc/6074/environ`) does not show any newly-added environment variables added via `setenv()`, nor does it show the updated values of any updated environment variables updated via `setenv()`. I discuss that in my answer below and show how to call `getenv()` directly in GDB to read new or updated values after program start. So, anyone using the accepted answer needs to at least understand that limitation.

---

This also answers the question: *"in GDB, how do you print all C-strings in an array of C-strings (ie: all `char*` C-strings in a `char**` variable), stopping once you reach a terminating NULL ptr value in the array."*

### How to print the entire `environ` variable, containing strings of all of your C or C++ program's environment variables, in GDB

### Quick summary

Read the values of new or updated environment variables in GDB. Ex: read the value of `"SHELL"` by using the `call` command in GDB to call the C function `getenv()`:

```bash
call getenv("SHELL")
```

Here are a couple ways to just spit out all values of the `environ` array of strings of environment variables, which is only expected to be accurate at program start:

From the bottom of Option 2 below, this is probably the easiest and fastest, while still producing nice output:

```bash
set $i = 0
printf "environ[%i]: \e[;94m%p\e[m: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
```

Now, press and hold down <kbd>Enter</kbd> until it outputs the full array and you get passed the `(nil): "(null)"` output at the end.

Or, go look at Option 4 below, and add my `print_environ` function to your `~/.gdbinit` file, and then run this, which is by far the best:

```bash
# print all environment variables as they are currently defined in your 
# C or C++ program
print_environ
```

*If you're just looking for the best answers, first read the note just below, then jump down to Options 2 and 4 below and be done.*

### A note about the `environ` variable and when it is updated

Important! The `environ` variable can be expected to only contain a snapshot of your environment variables as available to your program at program start. [The documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) states:

> This array of strings is made available to the process by the [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) call when a new program is started.

I have also done a lot of manual testing and trial-and-error in GDB while debugging my practice [environment_variables_getenv_and_setenv.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/environment_variables_getenv_and_setenv.c) C program in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master) repo, and have found the following to be true.

Once your program starts running, if it modifies any environment variables via [`setenv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html), then the `environ` variable will *not* be correspondingly updated! This is a quirk of how `environ` works. Rather, once you have added new environment variables *or* modified existing environment variables in your program, the *only* reliable way that I am aware of to recall their new values is via the [`getenv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) function. Luckily, GDB can call functions in your program directly via the GDB `call` command. So, as long as you have `#include <stdlib.h>` in your program within the section you are currently debugging in GDB, you can call the C function `getenv()` directly in GDB, like this!:

```bash
# This will NOT reliably show new or updated environment variables that your
# program has manipulated. 
# - In some rare cases, some of the environment variables may seem to show some
#   changes, but I cannot explain when, how, or why. So, once your program has
#   started adding new environment variables or modifying existing ones, don't
#   trust this output to be reliable anymore. Instead, call `getenv()` directly, 
#   as shown below. 
print_environ

# This *will* reliable read new or updated environment variables as manipulated
# by your program! 
# - Ex: read the current value of the "SHELL" environment variable via the
#   `getenv("SHELL")` C call: 
call getenv("SHELL")
```

Example call and output while debugging my [environment_variables_getenv_and_setenv.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/environment_variables_getenv_and_setenv.c) program:

```bash
(gdb) call getenv("SHELL")
$15 = 0x555555559c76 "bar_4"
```

You can of course also call `setenv()` inside GDB too, to create or modify an existing environment variable. Here, we will set `MY_NEW_VAR="whatever"`, and then get its value:

```bash
call setenv("MY_NEW_VAR", "whatever", 1)
call getenv("MY_NEW_VAR")
```

Here is my example call and output while debugging my program above:

```bash
(gdb) call setenv("MY_NEW_VAR", "whatever", 1)
$17 = 0
(gdb) call getenv("MY_NEW_VAR")
$18 = 0x555555559fcb "whatever"
```

Again, `print_environ`, which prints the full content of the `environ` array of strings, can *not* be trusted to contain any new environment variables or updated values for them. Use `call getenv("MY_NEW_VAR")` instead.

### Answer details

All Linux programs have a magical [external `char ** environ` variable](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) automatically set. It points to an array of pointers to strings which contain the environment variables in plain text. An example of the string at index `0`, for instance, meaning: `environ[0]` in C or C++, might be: `"SHELL=/bin/bash"`. The end of this array of pointers to strings is marked with a `NULL` (decimal `0`) value to indicate there are no more strings.

So, you can print all environment variables as follows. For `environ` to be available, you must be inside the `main()` function somewhere.

So, first begin debugging, then set a breakpoint at the start of `main()`, and run to that point. Then, run the following commands inside GDB.

Note that in all cases below, you can NOT copy and paste a chunk of my GDB commands at once, or else they won't run. GDB is a pain, and doesn't like the end-of-line chars, so you much manually type these commands or be very careful to copy only a single line of text at a time, and *not* include the end-of-line chars when copying the commands.

### Option 1 [easiest to remember]: set a convenience variable, call `print environ[$i++]`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> many times

```bash
# set a Convenience Variable
# (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html), i,
# initialized to zero
set $i = 0
# print the first string in the environment variable
print environ[$i++]
```

Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeatedly (dozens of times), or just hold it down for a bit, until you see `= 0x0` (the `NULL` terminating value) at some point, indicating that you have reached the end of the array of strings. Here is what the first few outputs and the last few outputs look like for me:

```bash
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) print environ[$i++]
$78 = 0x7fffffffe160 "SHELL=/bin/bash"
(gdb) 
$79 = 0x7fffffffe170 "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gabriel:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/gabriel:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952"
(gdb) 
$80 = 0x7fffffffe1f4 "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1"
(gdb) 
$81 = 0x7fffffffe207 "COLORTERM=truecolor"

.
.
.

$133 = 0x7fffffffeebe "GDMSESSION=ubuntu"
(gdb) 
$134 = 0x7fffffffeed0 "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
(gdb) 
$135 = 0x7fffffffef06 "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=559791"
(gdb) 
$136 = 0x7fffffffef2b "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/gabriel/Desktop/open_programming_tools.desktop"
(gdb) 
$137 = 0x7fffffffef81 "OLDPWD=/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world"
(gdb) 
$138 = 0x0
```

Notice again, the `= 0x0` (`NULL`) pointer value at the end to terminate the `environ` array of strings.

### Option 2 [even better!]: use `printf` in GDB to also print the index in the `environ` array that each string comes from!

I first wrote about this in my other answer here: [How to use `printf` in GDB in order to write a custom description around your variable output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903487/4561887). See that answer for more detail.

```bash
# Initialize a Convenience Variable
# (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html)
set $i = 0
printf "environ[%i]: %s\n", $i, environ[$i++]
# now keep pressing Enter for an amazing repeat effect!
```

The above output now looks like this instead. Notice that you can now easily see which index in the `environ` array of strings each string comes from! For the end of the array of strings, this time look for `(null)`:

```bash
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) printf "environ[%i]: %s\n", $i, environ[$i++]
environ[0]: SHELL=/bin/bash
(gdb) 
environ[1]: SESSION_MANAGER=local/gabriel:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/gabriel:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952
(gdb) 
environ[2]: QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
(gdb) 
environ[3]: COLORTERM=truecolor

.
.
.

environ[55]: GDMSESSION=ubuntu
(gdb) 
environ[56]: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
(gdb) 
environ[57]: GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=559791
(gdb) 
environ[58]: GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/gabriel/Desktop/open_programming_tools.desktop
(gdb) 
environ[59]: OLDPWD=/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world
(gdb) 
environ[60]: (null)
```

**Better still,** let's make it look more like the `print` output in Option 1 by putting quotes around the string, and printing the pointer address too, meaning the address of each C-string in the array of C-strings:

```bash
set $i = 0
printf "environ[%i]: %p: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
```

Now we get this output:

```bash
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) printf "environ[%i]: %p: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
environ[0]: 0x7fffffffe160: "SHELL=/bin/bash"
(gdb) 
environ[1]: 0x7fffffffe170: "SESSION_MANAGER=local/:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952"
(gdb) 
environ[2]: 0x7fffffffe1f4: "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1"
(gdb) 
environ[3]: 0x7fffffffe207: "COLORTERM=truecolor"

.
.
.

environ[55]: 0x7fffffffeebe: "GDMSESSION=ubuntu"
(gdb) 
environ[56]: 0x7fffffffeed0: "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
(gdb) 
environ[57]: 0x7fffffffef06: "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=559791"
(gdb) 
environ[58]: 0x7fffffffef2b: "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home//Desktop/open_programming_tools.desktop"
(gdb) 
environ[59]: 0x7fffffffef81: "OLDPWD=/home/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world"
(gdb) 
environ[60]: (nil): "(null)"
```

And lastly, **best yet**, add in some coloring characters (`\e[;34m` to make the foreground color (text) blue, and `\e[m` to clear the formatting), so that the pointer address is blue, like in GDB naturally when you use the `print` function:

```bash
set $i = 0
# print the pointer address as regular blue, like GDB's `print` function does
printf "environ[%i]: \e[;34m%p\e[m: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
# OR, use bright blue, which I like better because it's easier to see
printf "environ[%i]: \e[;94m%p\e[m: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
```

Now, we get the same output as before, except that all of the pointer addresses to each string, like `0x7fffffffe160`, are blue.

### Option 3 [easiest to do]: call `print *environ@100` with an arbitrary long array size (`100` in this case)

Just print `100` strings in the `environ` array of strings. If that's not enough to get to the end of the string and find the `0x0` (`NULL`) marker, then print `200` instead:

```bash
# print 100 elements; the `0x0` address marks the end; everything else after
# that is undefined behavior
print *environ@100

# Or print 200 elements; the `0x0` address marks the end; everything else after
# that is undefined behavior
print *environ@200
```

### Option 4 [best] Create a `~/.gdbinit` file with a custom `print_environ` function in it

This `print_environ` function will contain a GDB `while` loop to print all strings in the `environ` array until it reaches the `NULL` pointer at the end of the array.

Type the following, or copy and paste it, *one line at a time*, and with*out* newlines accidentally being included in what you copy paste, into GDB:

```bash
set $i = 0
while (environ[$i] != 0x0)
    print environ[$i++]
end
```

Here's my command and output, showing first and last several lines of output only, for brevity:

```bash
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) while (environ[$i] != 0x0)
 >    print environ[$i++]
 >end
$345 = 0x7fffffffe160 "SHELL=/bin/bash"
$346 = 0x7fffffffe170 "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gabriel:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/gabriel:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952"
$347 = 0x7fffffffe1f4 "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1"
$348 = 0x7fffffffe207 "COLORTERM=truecolor"

.
.
.

$400 = 0x7fffffffeebe "GDMSESSION=ubuntu"
$401 = 0x7fffffffeed0 "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
$402 = 0x7fffffffef06 "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=559791"
$403 = 0x7fffffffef2b "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/gabriel/Desktop/open_programming_tools.desktop"
$404 = 0x7fffffffef81 "OLDPWD=/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world"
```

If you see any errors when trying to run the above, it's probably because you copy-pasted multiple lines, or included newlines accidentally when copying, instead of manually typing line-by-line. Try it again, manually typing it this time.

**Even better, use the last `printf` command we produced at the end of Option 2 above:**

```bash
set $i = 0
while (environ[$i] != 0x0)
    printf "environ[%i]: \e[;94m%p\e[m: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
end
```

**To automate this though, because typing the above is irritating, create a `.gdbinit` file inside your user's home directory,** and copy and paste the following into it to create a `print_environ` function:

```bash
define print_environ
    set $i = 0
    while (environ[$i] != 0x0)
        printf "environ[%i]: \e[;94m%p\e[m: \"%s\"\n", $i, environ[$i], environ[$i++]
    end
end
```

Now, quit GDB, restart the debugger, set a breakpoint at the start of main, run to that breakpoint, and run your new function!:

```bash
print_environ
```

Now you'll see this as your command and output, except the string addresses will be in bright blue:

```bash
(gdb) print_environ 
environ[0]: 0x7fffffffe160: "SHELL=/bin/bash"
environ[1]: 0x7fffffffe170: "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gabriel-5570:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952,unix/gabriel-5570:/tmp/.ICE-unix/558952"
environ[2]: 0x7fffffffe1f4: "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1"
environ[3]: 0x7fffffffe207: "COLORTERM=truecolor"

.
.
.

environ[55]: 0x7fffffffeebe: "GDMSESSION=ubuntu"
environ[56]: 0x7fffffffeed0: "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
environ[57]: 0x7fffffffef06: "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=559791"
environ[58]: 0x7fffffffef2b: "GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/gabriel/Desktop/open_programming_tools.desktop"
environ[59]: 0x7fffffffef81: "OLDPWD=/home/gabriel/GS/dev/eRCaGuy_hello_world"
```

Done!

### Printing an `environ[n]` output above

The nice thing about seeing the `environ[n]` indices above is that it makes it easy to re-call just that one string in case you just want to check that one environment variable whose index you now know. Ex:

```bash
print environ[3]
```

But, as stated above in the section titled "A note about the `environ` variable and when it is updated", this cannot be relied upon to give you any new or updated environment variable information. Rather, you should use this GDB call to call the C function `getenv()` instead:

```bash
call getenv("MY_NEW_VAR")
```

### References

1. [`extern char **environ;`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) variable containing an array of strings of environment variables
2. My answer on [How to view a pointer like an array in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055978/4561887)
3. I first learned about this `set $i = 0` and `print environ[$i++]` technique, which uses [Convenience Variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#Convenience-Vars), here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html. Note that `RET` means to press <kbd>Return</kbd>:

   > Sometimes the artificial array mechanism is not quite enough; in moderately complex data structures, the elements of interest may not actually be adjacent—for example, if you are interested in the values of pointers in an array. One useful work-around in this situation is to use a convenience variable (see [Convenience Variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#Convenience-Vars)) as a counter in an expression that prints the first interesting value, and then repeat that expression via <kbd>RET</kbd>. For instance, suppose you have an array `dtab` of pointers to structures, and you are interested in the values of a field `fv` in each structure. Here is an example of what you might type:
   >
   > ```
   > set $i = 0
   > p dtab[$i++]->fv
   > RET
   > RET
   > …
   > ```
4. Where I learned the basics about how to write a `while` loop in GDB: [How do I write a loop in a gdb script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49675407/4561887)
5. Where I learned how to use the GDB `define` function to set a custom function of your own, as I do with `print_environ` above: [How to loop in a GDB script till program is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31678832/4561887)
6. My answer on [How to use `printf` in GDB in order to write a custom description around your variable output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903487/4561887)

   1. I tinkered with using `printf` here to customize my `environ[]` output, formatting, and custom descriptions.
7. My ANSI color format library in Bash, where I found the color format codes I needed: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/ansi_text_format_lib.sh

   1. My website article on how to use libraries in Bash: [How do you write, import, use, and test libraries in Bash?](https://gabrielstaples.com/bash-libraries/#gsc.tab=0)
8. More on writing scripts in GDB: https://sdimitro.github.io/post/scripting-gdb/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, nice! I've never heard of it. I'll save the link here for my future reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/

Comment: @GabrielStaples, already thank you so much for this answer! Is you master thesis still in the preprint feedback phase? Because: for whatever reason, *gdb* does not always notice modifications to the `environ` variable, therefore the output will be incorrect. Example. start a new `bash` login shell; identify its PID with `echo $$` then **update `environ`, e.g. with `export SHELL="foo"`; from another shell, attach to that process with `gdb -p $OTHER_PID`; `print environ[0]` will incorrectly show `"SHELL=/bin/bash"`, whereas `print getenv("SHELL")` will correctly show `"foo"`.

Comment: It is only after some "activity" (e.g. forking) happened in the debugged *bash* process that *gdb* will see the updated `environ` variable. For example: resume the execution of aforementioned *bash* process via `continue` on the *gdb* prompt; now on the *bash* prompt, execute `export SHELL="bar"`, followed by executing `whoami` (at that moment, *gdb* will probably give output such as "*`[Detaching after fork from child process $CHILD_PID]`*"; interrupt the bash process by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. *gdb*'s `print environ[0]` will correctly show the latest value `"SHELL=bar"`.

Comment: @Abdull, yeah, it hasn't been peer reviewed. You're the peer. I actually think I was wrong about how environment variables are updated. I don't think they are updated in place. Rather, they may be appended as new entries to the `environ` string array. Check to see if that is the case. Then, when you update `SHELL` via `export `SHELL="foo"`, perhaps that ends up as a new entry at the end of the `environ` array instead of updating the original `"foo"` string in place. Then, `getenv("SHELL")` perhaps walks the entire `environ` array, retaining the value last stored in `SHELL`.

Comment: @Abdull, see if that's the case. That's a hypothesis. I am unable to follow your instructions to debug a shell process. In one terminal, `echo $$` shows `1465609`. In another terminal, I run `gdb -p 1465609`. If I then run my `print_environ` function, it says `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.` If I press `r` to run it says, `Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.` So I don't know how to test what you are testing.

Comment: @Abdull, it turns out that `environ` can*not* be relied upon to contain any new or updated environment variable information after program start. See the new section in my answer titled "A note about the `environ` variable and when it is updated". Instead, you should call `call getenv("MY_NEW_VAR")` in GDB to obtain an environment variable's updated value, or any value of a newly-added environment variable.

Comment: @Abdull, anyway, I think this at least answers your initial question of how to print all strings in a string array, stopping at a NULL value in the array.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, I figured out why *Bash*'s `environ` becomes stale, and only refreshes when a non-builtin command is executed: when an environment variable is updated/exported in Bash, it is not directly put into `environ`, but rather (so to speak) placed in a cache within Bash. [`environ`  does get updated in `maybe_make_export_env ()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/variables.c#L5130), which e.g. is called from [`execute_disk_command (..)`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/bash-5.1/execute_cmd.c#L5494C14-L5494C14).

Comment: (permalinks: [`maybe_make_export_env ()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/variables.c#L5045) ... [`execute_disk_command ( )`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/execute_cmd.c#L5494C14-L5494C14) )

Comment: Regarding `print getenv("SHELL")` showing the up-to-date value even before an "*environment variable cash flush*": that is because the executed [`getenv(..)` function is a function from *Bash*](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/bash-5.1/lib/sh/getenv.c#L58), which is aware of Bash's "variable cache". When instead calling [*(g)libc*'s `getenv(..)`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.31/stdlib/getenv.c#L33), the potentially stale version will be printed: `print (char *) __GI_getenv("SHELL")`. ...`info symbol getenv` and `info function getenv` help with disambiguating.

Comment: so coming back to the initial point: for the particular case of *Bash*, because of *Bash*'s pecularity of "lazy-exporting" / "lazy-updating" environment variables (i.e., delaying the actual `environ` update until e.g. a subprocess is forked), it is correct that `environ` presents a seemingly outdated state. Executing `call maybe_make_export_env()` from gdb to the attached *Bash* process will synchronize the `environ` variable.