# Viewing environmental variables in a running program in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

In a core dump file, I am able to view environmental variables with:

```
$ gdb file core
>>> p __environ[0]
$1 = 0x7ffe6420dcbd "SHELL=/bin/bash"
>>> p __environ[1]
$2 = 0x7ffe6420dccd "TMUX=/tmp/tmux-1001/default,13871,0"
# basically the same as doing $ printenv
```

However, when I try and debug a normal executable:

```
# file.s
.globl main
main:
    ret

$ gcc file.s -ggdb3 -o file2
$ gdb -q file2
Reading symbols from file...
(No debugging symbols found in file)
>>> starti
>>> p __environ
No symbol "__environ" in current context.
```

How can I get access to the `environ` and `argv` ? One possible way is to examine its process file:

```
>>> python print(open('/proc/48011/environ').read().replace('\x00','\n'))
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMUX=/tmp/tmux-1001/default,13871,0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-RtmbGp8HSFcN/agent.14219
SSH_AGENT_PID=14220
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Where `48011` is from:

```
─── Threads ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[1] id 48011 name file from 0x0000000000401005 in _start
```

Comment: Please show how you built the executable, how you ran gdb and the gdb commands you ran (if any) leading up to that. That is, provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are probably missing some steps but can't say what unless you provide more details of what you actually did.

Comment: I suspect you just started gdb but did not actually run the executable. But that's just a guess based on the symptoms. Provide more info for a more definete answer.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the feedback, I updated the question, also seems it may be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32917097/651174

Comment: Is that your actual and complete gdb output? Or did you trim some of it? I'm expecting to see more than that. Can you show the full output?

Comment: @kaylum sure, for which code section, the second one where it says No symbol table?

Comment: everything from `gdb file` onwards.

Comment: @kaylum k updated.

Comment: @kaylum by the way, now it gives a different message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), GDB has a [`show environment` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html). On Linux, read also [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html), [gcore(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html), [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [gcc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) and conventions documented in [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html). See also [getenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) and [putenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html). You could also play with [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) and [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) and [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html). Be sure to read more documentation about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), perhaps in the [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

But if you compile on LInux an assembler file using `gcc file.s -ggdb3 -o file2`  that assembler file lacks [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information, nearly required by GDB.

So try writing a small `hello-world.c` program,  compile it using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -fverbose-asm -g -S hello-world.c` and examine (e.g. with [less(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)) the emitted `hello-world.s` assembler file. You'll see there a lot of DWARF related assembler directives. Compile it again with `gcc -v -Wall -Wextra -g -O hello-world.c -o helloworld` to understand what programs [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is starting for you. Read also the documentation about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Be of course aware of [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) startup code. On Linux, study the source code of both [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)) and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). All of them are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) or at least [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software, and you are allowed to download, study and improve their source code.

Read also the specification of Linux [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/841108). Consider also studying the source code of your Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/). See also [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/).

You might be interested by [linuxfromscratch.org](http://linuxfromscratch.org/) which gives detailed step by step instructions (to build an entire Linux distribution from scratch). Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [*Linux Assembler HowTo*](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/). Budget then several weeks of work.

Read also [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and study the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Read wikipages about [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))es, [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)s, [computer files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file), [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)s. Consider reading a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) and the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book and perhaps the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf).

Comment: good idea thanks for the help. I'll try with `-ggdb3` too. One question: when running an assembly program, do the environmental variables get added to the stack in the program memory? Or is this done as part of the c-startup code, and would not occur in hand-written assembly?

Comment: My opinion is that several dozens of pages are required to answer that question. Please follow all the hyperlinks given in my answer

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer I will check them out. In short though, assembly code written by itself does not add system environments, correct?

Comment: Assembler code are passive textual files, conventionally ended with `.s`. Of course they don't change the system environment. Only processes can change them